# How to check the multiple permission at single request in Android M?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I want to use the

1. android.permission.CAMERA
2. android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

in single request using

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Activity activity,new String permisionList[],int permissionRequestcode);
```

But my problem is at time I request only one permission,
I read about group-permission,But it's work for only Same group which one decided by Developer, Like `CONTACT_GROUP : read_contact,write_contact` etc.

I want create the custom group permission which ask me only one request & provide me only one response.

Thanks

Comment: You can't. Every group has own permission dialog which must be called.

Comment: @Ragaisis I want to display the all permission in only one request, I know If I request multiple permission but I got the single result

Comment: Easy way to ask multiple permissions, have a look at https://github.com/sachinvarma/EasyPermission

Answer (score 76):

You can ask multiple permissions (from different groups) in a single request. For that, you need to add all the permissions to the string array that you supply as the first parameter to the requestPermissions API like this:

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
                                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
```

On doing this, you will see the permission popup as a stack of multiple permission popups. Ofcourse you need to handle the acceptance and rejection (including the "Never Ask Again") options of each permissions. The same has been beautifully explained over [here](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en).

Comment: Please read my question perfectly.. I want check all permission in single request.. Not  multiple dialog. & bro your link is not related with my question... sorry..

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!

Comment: I had to add `this`, otherwise it wouldn't work `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                   ...} ,ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);`

Comment: @Yonjuni it was not checking the the list of permissions whether is it granted or not...

Answer (score 31):

First initialize permission request code

```
public  static final int PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST = 123;
```

Check android version

```
 private void checkAndroidVersion() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        checkPermission();

    } else {
        // write your logic here
    }

}
```

check multiple permission code

```
 private void checkPermission() {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) + ContextCompat
            .checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                (getActivity(), Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ||
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale
                        (getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

      Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                    "Please Grant Permissions to upload profile photo",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE",
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            requestPermissions(
                                    new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                            .READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                    PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST);
                        }
                    }).show();
        } else {
            requestPermissions(
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission
                            .READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                    PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST);
        }
    } else {
        // write your logic code if permission already granted
    }
}
```

call back method after grant permission by user

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST:
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
               boolean cameraPermission = grantResults[1] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
               boolean readExternalFile = grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

                if(cameraPermission && readExternalFile)
                {
                    // write your logic here 
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.content),
                        "Please Grant Permissions to upload profile photo",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("ENABLE",
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                requestPermissions(
                                        new String[]{Manifest.permission
                                                .READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                        PERMISSIONS_MULTIPLE_REQUEST);
                            }
                        }).show();
                }
           }
           break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty sketchy to rely on a magic number (PERMISSION_GRANTED = 0).

Comment: quite untidy way for requesting multiple permissions.

Comment: let me know why?

Comment: Awesome answer ! Worked perfect

Comment: This answer has a bug .. if you denied a permission twice continuously , when you click on enable on Snackbar , Snackbar will appear again and again and again

Answer (score 6):

There is no hack available at this stage to circumvent asking for permissions from different groups together. That is the nature of how android has developed runtime permissions, to give users a choice of which permissions to accept. Of course not accepting all permissions required by an app, may make the app fail to work properly.

CAMERA and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE are both [regarded as dangerous permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#defining), and in separate groups, thus both requiring a [runtime permission request.](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Once permission is granted for a particular group, it does not need to be requested again for the lifetime of the app run, or until it is revoked if given as a default setting.

[image]

[image]

The only thing you can do is ask the user to accept the decisions as default, which can be revoked, [by using "never ask again"](http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and stumbled on this [library](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter).

Basically you can ask for multiple permissions sequentially, plus you can add listeners to popup a snackbar if the user denies your permission.

[image: dexter_sample]

Comment: He did not say to introduce a library

Answer (score 4):

For multiple permission you can use this code :

```
final private int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS = 124;

private void insertDummyContactWrapper() {
    List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<String>();

    final List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))
        permissionsNeeded.add("GPS");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Read Contacts");
    if (!addPermission(permissionsList, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS))
        permissionsNeeded.add("Write Contacts");

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
            // Need Rationale
            String message = "You need to grant access to " + permissionsNeeded.get(0);
            for (int i = 1; i < permissionsNeeded.size(); i++)
                message = message + ", " + permissionsNeeded.get(i);
            showMessageOKCancel(message,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
                        }
                    });
            return;
        }
        requestPermissions(permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
        return;
    }

    insertDummyContact();
}

private boolean addPermission(List<String> permissionsList, String permission) {
    if (checkSelfPermission(permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(permission);
        // Check for Rationale Option
        if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permission))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: if you are using marshmellow then you have to use these separate permission

Answer (score 4):

**Here i have a simple solution, - (Multiple permission checking)**

```
String[] permissions = new String[]{
  Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALL_LOG,
  Manifest.permission.READ_CALL_LOG,
  Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS,
  Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS}; // Here i used multiple permission check
```

**Then call it in Oncreate**

```
 if (checkPermissions()) { //  permissions  granted.
    getCallDetails();
 }
```

**Finally, copy the below code**

```
private boolean checkPermissions() {
  int result;
  List<String> listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();

   for (String p : permissions) {
     result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), p);
     if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
       listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
     }
   }

   if (!listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty()) {
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
     return false;
   }
     return true;
}


@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS: {
      if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {  // permissions granted.
           getCallDetails(); // Now you call here what ever you want :)
        } else {
             String perStr = "";
               for (String per : permissions) {
                   perStr += "\n" + per;
                }   // permissions list of don't granted permission
              }
            return;
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: If I can, why this condition tests only index 0? `if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)`

Comment: the onrequestpermission doesn't work because check only the first granResult...

Comment: What is the value of `MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS`?

Answer (score 3):

As said earlier, currently every permission group has own permission dialog which must be called separately.

You will have different dialog boxes for each permission group but you can surely check the result together in onRequestPermissionsResult() callback method.

[Here is a working example link, may be useful for someone.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35495855/1234913)

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem and below is the workaround I came up with:

```
public boolean checkForPermission(final String[] permissions, final int permRequestCode, int msgResourceId) {
        final List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
            final String perm = permissions[i];
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), permissions[i]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[i])) {
                    final AlertDialog dialog = AlertDialog.newInstance( getResources().getString(R.string.permission_title), getResources().getString(msgResourceId) );
                    dialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // add the request.
                            permissionsNeeded.add(perm);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    dialog.show( getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "HCFAlertDialog" );
                } else {
                    // add the request.
                    permissionsNeeded.add(perm);
                }
            }
        }

        if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
            // go ahead and request permissions
            requestPermissions(permissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[permissionsNeeded.size()]), permRequestCode);
            return false;
        } else {
            // no permission need to be asked so all good...we have them all.
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And you call the above method like this:

```
if ( checkForPermission( new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, 
Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_PERMISSION_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_RESULT, R.string.permission_image) ) {
                        // DO YOUR STUFF

                    }
```

Comment: but you check your code? In this code also show native permission dialog multiple time.

Comment: @Zala Janaksinh yeah...android will display the permissions individually but you make just a single request.

Comment: I know that,so it's my problem. bro.. may be android resolved this in next update.

Answer (score 1):

check More than one Permission and Request if Not Granted

```
 public void checkPermissions(){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.CAMERA)==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        //Do_SOme_Operation();
    }else{
        requestStoragePermission();
    }
}

public void requestStoragePermission(){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this
            ,new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.CAMERA},1234);
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode){
        case 1234:if(grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
  // Do_SOme_Operation();
        }

        default:super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode,permissions,grantResults);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
       // **For multiple permission you can use this code :**

       // **First:**
//Write down in onCreate method.

         if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{
                                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                    android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);

         }

        //**Second:**
    //Write down in a activity.
     @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                               String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
            switch (requestCode) {
                case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST:

                    if (grantResults.length > 0
                            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                Intent i = new Intent(SplashActivity.this,
                                        HomeActivity.class);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }
                        }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);

                    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on what i've searched, i think this is the best answers that i've found out [Android 6.0 multiple permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34343101/1025780)

Answer (score 0):

Adding generic code for different types of permissions. Copy-paste with minor changes. Read the "TODO" comments in the code below.

Make the following Activity your Launcher Activity:

```
public class PermissionReqActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CODE_WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION = 332;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_ALL = {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}; //TODO You can Add multiple permissions here.
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 223;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_permission_req);
        context = this;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            boolean allPermissionsGranted = true;
            ArrayList<String> toReqPermissions = new ArrayList<>();

            for (String permission : PERMISSIONS_ALL) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    toReqPermissions.add(permission);

                    allPermissionsGranted = false;
                }
            }
            if (allPermissionsGranted)
                //TODO Now some permissions are very special and require Settings Activity to launch, as u might have seen in some apps. handleWriteSettingsPermission() is an example for WRITE_SETTINGS permission. If u don't need very special permission(s), replace handleWriteSettingsPermission() with initActivity().
                handleWriteSettingsPermission();
            else
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        toReqPermissions.toArray(new String[toReqPermissions.size()]), PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
            boolean allPermGranted = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                if (grantResults[i] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted: " + permissions[i], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    allPermGranted = false;
                    finish();
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (allPermGranted)
                handleWriteSettingsPermission();//TODO As mentioned above, use initActivity() here if u dont need very special permission WRITE_SETTINGS
        }
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    private void handleWriteSettingsPermission() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (Settings.System.canWrite(context)) {
                initActivity();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enable this permission for " +
                        getApplicationInfo().loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, CODE_WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION);
            }
        }
    }

//TODO You don't need the following onActivityResult() function if u dont need very special permissions.

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && requestCode == CODE_WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION) {
            if (Settings.System.canWrite(this))
                initActivity();
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permissions not granted: " + Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                finish();
            }
        }
    }

    private void initActivity() {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on vedval i have this solution.

```
public boolean checkForPermission(final String[] permissions, final int permRequestCode) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        return true;
    }
    final List<String> permissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < permissions.length; i++) {
        final String perm = permissions[i];
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permissions[i]) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissions[i])) {
                Snackbar.make(phrase, R.string.permission_location, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE)
                        .setAction(android.R.string.ok, new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                permissionsNeeded.add(perm);
                            }
                        });
            } else {
                // add the request.
                permissionsNeeded.add(perm);
            }
        }
    }

    if (permissionsNeeded.size() > 0) {
        // go ahead and request permissions
        requestPermissions(permissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[permissionsNeeded.size()]), permRequestCode);
        return false;
    } else {
        // no permission need to be asked so all good...we have them all.
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Callback received when a permissions request has been completed.
 */
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_LOCATION) {
        int i = 0;
        for (String permission : permissions ){
            if ( permission.equals(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) && grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                initLocationManager();
            }
            i++;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am late, but i want tell the library which i have ended with.

[**RxPermission**](https://github.com/tbruyelle/RxPermissions) is best library with reactive code, which makes permission code unexpected just 1 line.

```
RxPermissions rxPermissions = new RxPermissions(this);
rxPermissions
.request(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
         Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
.subscribe(granted -> {
    if (granted) {
       // All requested permissions are granted
    } else {
       // At least one permission is denied
    }
});
```

add in your `build.gradle`

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.tbruyelle:rxpermissions:0.10.1'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.rxbinding2:rxbinding:2.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use the dependency named dexter as given below:
https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter
by this you can get one or many permission easily:
this is the given code

```
    Dexter.withContext(this).
               withPermissions(Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
          Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
               .withListener(new MultiplePermissionsListener() {
                  @Override
                    public void onPermissionsChecked(MultiplePermissionsReport 
                    multiplePermissionsReport) {
                    displaySong();
                  }

                @Override
                public void    onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(List<PermissionRequest> list,     
        PermissionToken permissionToken) {

                    permissionToken.continuePermissionRequest();

                }
            }).check();
```

Answer (score -3):

For Asking Multiple Permission At Once You Can Use this Method [link](https://github.com/Kishanjvaghela/Ask-Permission)

```
compile 'com.kishan.askpermission:askpermission:1.0.3'
```

If you got conflicting in support library then

```
compile('com.kishan.askpermission:askpermission:1.0.3', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support'
})
```

Now ask for Permission

```
new AskPermission.Builder(this)
    .setPermissions(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    .setCallback(/* PermissionCallback */)
    .setErrorCallback(/* ErrorCallback */)
    .request(/* Request Code */);
```

permission granted callback

```
  public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode) {
// your code  }
```

permission denied callback

```
 public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode) {
// your code}
```

ErrorCallbacks

```
public void onShowRationalDialog(PermissionInterface permissionInterface, int requestCode) {
// Alert user by Dialog or any other layout that you want.
// When user press OK you must need to call below method.
permissionInterface.onDialogShown();
```

}

```
public void onShowSettings(PermissionInterface permissionInterface, int requestCode) {
// Alert user by Dialog or any other layout that you want.
// When user press OK you must need to call below method.
// It will open setting screen.
permissionInterface.onSettingsShown();
```

}

Comment: A link-only answer is not recommended. It is liable to downvotes, which is only just a warning, and will eventually get deleted.