# How to ask for multiple permissions one after another?

Tags: android, android-permissions

My app requires to access **CAMERA** and **WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE** permissions.

Once my app loads I want to ask user to allow both of these permissions one after another. I have this code:

```
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
    }


    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);

    }
```

Now once my app loads it asks for the first permission but never asks for the second until I reload the entire app again.

How do I ask both of these permissions from the user once app loads?

Comment: check this link: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the multiple permission at single request in Android M?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040355/how-to-check-the-multiple-permission-at-single-request-in-android-m)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to put all of the permissions into one `String` array:

```
new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA}
```

This way, users will be shown a dialog with all of the permissions and they can decide to deny or grant each permission individually. As soon as they are finished, your `Activity` will be called with `onRequestPermissionsResult()`.

One of the parameters of this method is an array of type `int` named **grantResults** which you can evaluate to know which permissions were granted.

Answer (score 3):

You can ask for more than one permission in `requestPermissions()`. It takes an array of permission names, not just a single permission.

Note, though, that whatever you include in that array will be asked for, even if you already have that permission.

So, you can do something like this:

```
  private static final String[] PERMS_TAKE_PICTURE={
    CAMERA,
    WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
  };

  private void gimmePermission() {
    if (!canTakePicture()) {
      ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
        netPermissions(PERMS_TAKE_PICTURE), RESULT_PERMS_TAKE_PICTURE);
    }
  }

  private boolean hasPermission(String perm) {
    return(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, perm)==
      PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
  }

  private boolean canTakePicture() {
    return(hasPermission(CAMERA) && hasPermission(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE));
  }

  private String[] netPermissions(String[] wanted) {
    ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String perm : wanted) {
      if (!hasPermission(perm)) {
        result.add(perm);
      }
    }

    return(result.toArray(new String[result.size()]));
  }
```

`netPermissions()` takes a `String[]` of the permissions you want and returns a `String[]` of the permissions that you do not yet hold, which you can then pass along to `requestPermissions()`.

(code derived from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Permissions/tutorial/finish/RuntimePermTutorial))