# Android M and above location course and location fine returning permission granted true

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions

I am trying to access the users locations and just sorting out the permission side of things. So my understanding is that on 23 and above regardless of the manifest the user must grant permission.

So I have it in the manifest like this for older versions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

For the newer >= 23 I am testing like this before showing a dialog:

```
// Check for runtime location permissions
private boolean hasRunTimeLocationPermission() {
    int courseLocationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    return  (courseLocationPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );
}
```

The way I understood it that should return false the first time but it is returning true.

Does the user actually have to disable location services or is it considered 'dangerous" and it have to be approved the first time?

Also I am using a new emulator api 23, when I look into location permissions it says no apps have requested location.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Are you checking this condition in fragments?

Comment: Yes I am does that change it?

Comment: In the on start method of the fragment

Comment: What is your target SDK? Apps targeting 22 or lower will be treated differently.

Comment: @Raghavendra thanks for checking just put the same code into the main activity and same result, so its not because of fragment.

Comment: you are supposed to receive the user permission grant in a callback called onRequestsPermissionsResult. check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39810434/android-api-23-requesting-multiple-permissions/40088998#40088998

Comment: What is the state of permission in Setting->Apps->Permissions->Location ?

Comment: Can u check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33407250/checkselfpermission-method-is-not-working-in-targetsdkversion-22

Comment: @user1506104 That code you pointed to if ro requesting permission after it is established that the permission is not allowed.

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar Thanks, The permission for the app is set to on. I thought that this was not done be default?

Comment: It should not be done by default: `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` belogs to a dangerous permission group. But if you requested `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` earlier **and** the user granted permission then this will be applied to all permissions in the LOCATION permission group. Did your app ask for permission to access the fine location?

Comment: @0X0nosugar new emulator have not requested or approved anything

Comment: @MadhukarHebbar This is what was causing the problem Thanks! for some reason the emulator has started with that permission being set to true. Do you know what that would happen?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: what did you get when installed in a physical device?

Comment: Only tested it on physical below marshmallow.

Comment: this code works fine on my M device. could be an emulator issue.

Comment: Ok thanks appreciate it

Comment: one more thing, as your are using Google map api, make sure that your emulator is running at least on Android 6.0 (**Google APIs**) target.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
// Check for runtime location permissions
private boolean hasRunTimeLocationPermission() {
    int courseLocationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    return  (courseLocationPermission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It doesn't change anything though sorry.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
private boolean hasRunTimeLocationPermission() {
 if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            return false;
        }
 else
        {
           return true;
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions like this :-

```
Check permissions like this :-

if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
            //Show Information about why you need the permission
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Need Location Permission");
            builder.setMessage("This app needs location permission.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION_CONSTANT);
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        } else if (permissionStatus.getBoolean(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,false)) {
            //Previously Permission Request was cancelled with 'Dont Ask Again',
            // Redirect to Settings after showing Information about why you need the permission
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Need Location Permission");
            builder.setMessage("This app needs location permission.");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                    sentToSettings = true;
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                    Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
                    intent.setData(uri);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PERMISSION_SETTING);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Go to Permissions to Grant Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        } else {
            //just request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION_CONSTANT);
        }

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = permissionStatus.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,true);
        editor.commit();


    } else {
        //You already have the permission, just go ahead.
        proceedAfterPermission();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to Manifest even for api>23

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

And then ask for runtime permissions like this :-

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                1);
```

And to handle the restults, use this:-

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                   String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case 1: {

      // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
      if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // permission was granted, yay! Do the
        } else {

            // permission denied, boo! 
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Permission denied to read your External storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        return;
    }
}
}
```