# How to ask and accept all permissions in only one confirm alert dialog in Android 6.0

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-permissions, user-experience

I am create an app which need to grand four permissions: Contact, Phone, Storage. I think it really annoy user and I want to ask them only one dialog. I have try this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36061318/5241603), but there are dialog to show confirm for each permission.

**How to ask only one rational dialog with button confirm and cancel?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't club multiple permissions into one. There will be a separate dialog for each permission that is requested even you are passing permission as an array.

Comment: Yub, thank. I think it cannot be hacked more for now. All I can do is to tell rational message explain user about each permission.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is **you can not**, It is not possible to ask multiple permission in same dialog as of now.

You can request for multiple permission, which will be displayed in single dialog of each.

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1; 
String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION};

if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
}
```

This is how it will ask for permission to user.

[image]

[image]

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34342816/android-6-0-multiple-permissions) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040355/how-to-check-the-multiple-permission-at-single-request-in-android-m) for more details.

Comment: thank, I think what I can do is just explain user before show these permission.

Comment: yes you can give custom dialog and tell user why do you want all those permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following link:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity, java.lang.String[], int)

```
   void requestPermissions (Activity activity, 
            String[] permissions, 
            int requestCode);
```

requestPermissions method takes an array in which you can pass multiple permissions. See if it works for you. Otherwise, you can pass it separately only.

Comment: I knew this solution. But my question is to make a custom message to ask only one time to accept all or not accept in only **one click**.