# How do I request multiple runtime permissions in single dialogue?

Tags: android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I'm currently only able to ask each Android Runtime permission group sequentially. With 4-5 app permissions on open, that's 4-5 back-to-back dialogues with 4-5 clicks before first open. It's UX suicide.

How do I code this to ask all 4-5 permissions listed in a single dialogue with a single click? Still a permission upon runtime (app open), but more user friendly.

Like the old listed method upon downloading, only the permission occurs at runtime.

Thank you.

(Edit: No solution for this is found on any other threads)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check the multiple permission at single request in Android M?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34040355/how-to-check-the-multiple-permission-at-single-request-in-android-m)

Comment: That's not possible. But usually you don't need to ask for the whole list of permissions right at the first start of your app. Try to ask for each permission just right before that specific permission is really necessary.

Comment: @oemel09 Appreciate that. The 4 permissions are required for the app to function (automated user accts, location, etc). We have trimmed away other permissions that are only needed at time of action (not first open), but can only trim so much. 

Keeping in mind the app also has a terms of service and other intro guidance needed for UX. It's first open bombardment. What would be ideal is all permissions and TOS in one single click for user. 

There's always a way. Anything is possible, just need to find it.

Comment: But there is yet no way of doing this. The user can always decide to only grant one permission to your app and deny another one. With Android M Google got rid of the 'download this and accept everything' concept.

Comment: Till  November 1, 2018 you could compile your app with an old targetSdkVersion to make use of the old permission system where each permission is granted by default once the app is downloaded. But by now google won't allow you to upload apps with a targetSdkVersion less than 26

Comment: @oemel09 Hmm, not looking for the exact old system (ask on download), still looking for runtime ask, just all in single dialogue. It also doesn't help how misleading Google's permissions are. If anyone else has other strategies, I'd love to hear them. For now our best option for achieving this will be direct APK download and removing from the play store (and their tax). Not ideal, but best option I can see. Thanks for the feedback.